# how to make a string to date and show it on graph

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import datetime    
a = '20180204'
a_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(a,'%Y%m%d')
```

the result is

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 0, 0)
```

and `print(a_time)`

```
2018-02-04 00:00:00
```

I want it just show the day like'2018-02-04'. Which command can i use?

And I show it with matplotlib

```
x_list = list()
y_list = list()
for i in range(0,len(stock_order)): # stock_order is a list of tuple
    x = stock_order[i][0]
    xt = datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d')
    x_list.append(x)
    y = stock_order[i][1]
    y_list.append(y)
plt.plot(x_list,y_list)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB6ZZ.png)

How can I make X-axis show clearly and beautiful?

Comment: If you want only the date, you need to ask datetime.date(2018, 2, 4), not datetime.datetime, which will just assume time of midnight if not time given. If you want the '-' character between the dates, you can format it using date.strftime("%y-%m-%d"). For your x-asis, you need to format it using major and minor axis locator ticks. You can see examples in here: https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html

Comment: Do you mean `x_list.append(xt)`?

Comment: I want  X-axis show in time type